# Calling a function for ALL child components

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have 3 components. They parent layout, a select box, and a panel this is generated x times from some data.

```
<Layout>
 <Dropdown>
 <Panel>
 <Panel>
 <Panel>
```

I'm trying to make it so when the select value changes, the contents of each panel changes. The changes are made by doing some math between the new select value, and data that is stored in the panel component. Each panel has different data.

Layout.js

```
updateTrueCost(selected){
 this.refs.panel.setTrueCost
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                Show me the true cost in
                <CurrencyDrop currencyChange = {(e) => this.updateTrueCost(e)} data = {this.state.data} />
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            {this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
                <Panel ref="panel" key = {index} paneldata= {item} />
            ))}                 
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Panel.js

```
setTrueCost(selected){
 //Do some math
 this.setState({truecost: mathresult})
}

render(){
  return(
     <div>
      {this.state.truecost}
     </div>
  )
}
```

CurrencyDrop.js

```
onHandelChange(e){
    this.props.currencyChange(e);
}

render(){
   return(
    <Select
     onChange={this.onHandelChange.bind(this)}
     options={options} />
   )
}
```

The current result is only the last panel updates when the select changes. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the ref handling, but I must not be searching the right terms because I can't find any related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling ref's method use React build-in lifecycle methods.

```
class Panel extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps (newProps) {
        // compare old and new data
        // make some magic if data updates
        if (this.props.panelData !== newProps.panelData) {
            this.setState({trueCost: someMath()});
        }
    }

    render () {
        return <div>{this.state.trueCost}</div>
    }
}
```

Then just change input props and all data will be updated automatically.

Comment: Awesome, even better than what I was looking for.